# Why does aws code deploy throw "No passwd entry for user 'ec2-user'" error inspite of running everything as root?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sudo, aws-code-deploy

Here are the error messages:

[image]
[image]

Here are the concerned files:

stop.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
pkill -f node
```

appspec.yml

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /var/www/
permissions:
  - object: /var/www/
    owner: root
    mode: 777
hooks:
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: scripts/install.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
  AfterInstall:
    - location: scripts/post_install.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: scripts/run.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
  ApplicationStop:
    - location: scripts/stop.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
  ValidateService:
    - location: scripts/validate.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
```

Here are the OS detail:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-2-33:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

I tried running all hooks as ec2-user 'ubuntu' as well, results are the same.

Answer (score 0):

`ec2-user` is just default instance user.  In all linux, you cannot execute any system command without first issue `sudo`

Fix :

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo pkill -f node
```

Comment: doesn't work. Please try yourself before answering. The stop.sh script is already triggered as root, so I guess it doesn't need you to write sudo before every command.

Answer (score 0):

If you have successfully deployed the sam application in the instance before, the application stop script is actually running from last successful revision, could you check the application stop script in the last successful revision and it contains everything that you expected?

If the ApplicationStop is not right inside the last successful revision, you might want to set the --ignore-application-stop-failures option. You